# PySpark get related Row from DF List object value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has an ID column and a related Array column which contains the IDs of its related records.

```
ID | NAME | RELATED_IDLIST
--------------------------
123 | mike | [345,456]
345 | alen | [789]
456 | sam  | [789,999]
789 | marc | [111]
555 | dan  | [333]
```

From the above, I need to build a relationship between all the related child IDs together to its parent ID. The resultant DF should be like

```
ID | NAME | RELATED_IDLIST
 --------------------------
 123 | mike | [345,456,789,999,111]
 345 | alen | [789,111]
 456 | sam  | [789,999,111]
 789 | marc | [111]
 555 | dan  | [333]
```

I need help figuring out the above.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do this?

Comment: Heloo, i am not sure of where to start. like how to get the record for each.. as it involves cyclic dependency

Comment: "not sure" means in general terms "lazy". Right now your question reads as "code on demand for which I am not paying aside of rep up-voting. So start somewhere and see what happens. Many eager to assist you in the quest of gaining knowledge but only if you show effort. Thus buy the book from VanDerPlas to get you kick-started with Python Data Science and return to us with code you wrote which may throw a bunch of tracebacks to you ;-)

Comment: reopening the question As It is interesting question, I want to see the solution how it will be implemented in ```spark```

Answer (score 0):

By Using `Self joins` and `Window functions` you can tackle this problem.
I have divided the code into 5 steps. The algorithm is as follows :

1. Explode array list to create singular record (no more arrays in data)
2. Self join Id and Related (renamed the RELATED_IDLIST column) columns
3. Reduce the records of which have same a_id into one array and b_id into another array
4. Merge the two array list columns into one combined array and rank the resultant records based on highest size of each resulting combined array
5. pick the records having rank as 1

you can try the following code:

```
# importing necessary functions for later use
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,col,collect_set,array_union,size
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank,desc

# need set cross join to True if spark version < 3
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", True)

############### STEP 0 #####################################
# creating the above mentioned dataframe
id_cols = [123,345,456,789,555]
name_cols = ['mike','alen','sam','marc','dan']
related_idlist_cols = [[345,456],[789],[789,999],[111],[333]]

list_of_rows = [(each_0,each_1,each_2) for each_0, each_1, each_2 in zip(id_cols,name_cols,related_idlist_cols)]
cols_name = ['ID','NAME','RELATED_IDLIST']

# this will result in above mentioned dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(list_of_rows,cols_name)

############### STEP 1: Explode values  #####################################
# explode function converts arraylist to atomic records
# one record having array size two will result in two records 
#                                       + -> 123, mike,129
# 123, mike , explode(['129'.'9029']) -->
#                                        +-> 123, mike,9029
df_1 = df.select(col('id'),col('name'),explode(df.RELATED_IDLIST).alias('related'))

############### STEP 2 : Self Join with Data  #####################################
# creating dataframes with different column names, for joining them later
a = df_1.withColumnRenamed('id','a_id').withColumnRenamed('name','a_name').withColumnRenamed('related','a_related')
b = df_1.withColumnRenamed('id','b_id').withColumnRenamed('name','b_name').withColumnRenamed('related','b_related')

# this is an example outer join & self join 
df_2 = a.join(b, a.a_related == b.b_id, how='left').orderBy(a.a_id)

############### STEP 3 : create Array Lists #####################################
# using collect_set we can reduce values of a particular kind into one set (we are reducing 'related' records, based on 'id')
df_3  = df_2.select('a_id','a_name',collect_set('a_related').over(Window.partitionBy(df_2.a_id)).\
                    alias('a_related_ids'),collect_set('b_related').over(Window.partitionBy(df_2.b_id)).alias('b_related_ids'))

# merging two sets into one column and also calculating resultant the array size
df_4 = df_3.select('a_id','a_name',array_union('a_related_ids','b_related_ids').alias('combined_ids')).withColumn('size',size('combined_ids'))

# ranking the records to pick the ideal records 
df_5 = df_4.select('a_id','a_name','combined_ids',dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy('a_id').orderBy(desc('size'))).alias('rank'))

############### STEP 4 : Selecting Ideal Records  #####################################
# picking records of rank 1, but this will have still ducplicates so removing them using distinct and ordering them by id
df_6 = df_5.select('a_id','a_name','combined_ids').filter(df_5.rank == 1).distinct().orderBy('a_id')

############### STEP 5 #####################################
display(df_6)
```